# ANR: Input dispatching timed out - Creating a Bitmap from an URL

Tags: android

In my Android app, I'm creating Bitmap from image URL. Below is the code I have written to create Bitmap from image URL--

```
 public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src)
    {
        try
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My app is on play-store and this code affecting few devices as they are getting "Input dispatching timed out" ANR. Below is the ANR details I got from Google Play Console's "ANR & Crashes" section--

"***Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago. Wait queue length: 60. Wait queue head age: 10502.8ms.)***"

Below is the complete log from Google Play Console--

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x75a2c598 self=0xa4e84400
  | sysTid=522 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xa7d13534
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=114 stm=42 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0xbe467000-0xbe469000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 0000000000048cb4  /system/lib/libc.so (__ppoll+20)
  #01  pc 000000000001cf3f  /system/lib/libc.so (poll+46)
  #02  pc 0000000000012cb7  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so (???)
  #03  pc 000000000000f24b  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so (???)
  #04  pc 000000000000e5cd  /system/framework/arm/boot-conscrypt.oat (Java_com_android_org_conscrypt_NativeCrypto_SSL_1read__JLjava_io_FileDescriptor_2Lcom_android_org_conscrypt_NativeCrypto_00024SSLHandshakeCallbacks_2_3BIII+192)
  at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read (Native method)
  at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read (OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:761)
- locked <0x06eb358f> (a java.lang.Object)
  at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read (Okio.java:142)
  at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read (AsyncTimeout.java:218)
  at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf (RealBufferedSource.java:312)
  at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf (RealBufferedSource.java:306)
  at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict (RealBufferedSource.java:202)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse (HttpConnection.java:210)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders (HttpTransport.java:81)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse (HttpEngine.java:960)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse (HttpEngine.java:836)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:480)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:422)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:256)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream (DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
  at come.xyz.myapp.util.AppHelper.getBitmapFromURL (AppHelper.java:66)
  at come.xyz.myapp.Adapters.ScratchersAdapter.instantiateItem (ScratchersAdapter.java:706)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem (ViewPager.java:1004)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1218)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1086)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter (ViewPager.java:534)
  at come.xyz.myapp.widgets.InfiniteViewPager.setAdapter (InfiniteViewPager.java:40)
  at come.xyz.myapp.Fragments.DailyScratchersFragment.updateAdapter (DailyScratchersFragment.java:965)
  at come.xyz.myapp.Fragments.DailyScratchersFragment.onCaughtContent (DailyScratchersFragment.java:750)
  at come.xyz.coresdk.CoreLibrary.onCaughtContent (CoreLibrary.java:591)
  at come.xyz.coresdk.asynctasks.CatchScratcherSetTask.onPostExecute (CatchScratcherSetTask.java:82)
  at come.xyz.coresdk.asynctasks.CatchScratcherSetTask.onPostExecute (CatchScratcherSetTask.java:22)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish (AsyncTask.java:660)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1 (AsyncTask.java)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage (AsyncTask.java:677)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6317)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:872)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

There are couple of question posted before for the same issue on stackoverflow but none of them I found useful for me. Please let me know if i can provide more information for this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually putting "Creating Bitmap from URL" code in Asynctask resolved my issue. Below is my code--

```
public class GetBitmapTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
{
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        Bitmap map = null;
        for (String url : urls)
        {
            map = createBitmapFromURL(url);
        }
        return map;
    }

    // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap resultBitmap)
    {

    }


    public Bitmap createBitmapFromURL(String src)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is how I called this task--

```
Bitmap mBitmap = new GetBitmapTask().execute(strImgUrl).get();
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are downloading image on main thread and that will cause ANR , i believe that you need to make it in background thread like asynctask or use one of these 3rd parties
https://github.com/bumptech/glide or http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 1):

May be the below line causes the problem

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Instead of doing network functions by this method,, create an AsyncTask for the same, The ANR is caused may be because the the process is too lengthy, so instead of enabling strickmode use AsyncTask

Comment: I got what you are saying, I'll try the same and let you know the status. Thank you.

Comment: that two lines are used for logging every thing in the thread
please check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder

Comment: I once used the StrictMode Policy for making network calls in the UI thread, But sometimes it leads to ANR , so then I changed it into AsyncTask,,  For downloading images it is better to use Picasso or Glide ,, it removes so much code and is more efficient